Does pressure affect the enthalpy of formation?
In a complete combustion reaction, coal and air (both at $300K$ and $2$ atm) react to produce carbon dioxide which exits the reactor at the same temperature and pressure as it entered.
$$\mathbf{C+O_2}\rightarrow \mathbf{CO_2}$$
Nitrogen is present but can be ignored as it doesn't interact with anything.
In trying to find the rate of heat to a boiler in terms of $kJ/kmol$ of coal entering, I used the energy rate balance equation in a molar basis.
$$0= \dot{Q}+\dot{n}_C\bar{h}_C+\dot{n}_{O_2}\bar{h}_{O_2}-\dot{n}_{CO_2}\bar{h}_{CO_2}$$
$$\frac{\dot{Q}}{\dot{n}_C}=\frac{\dot{n}_{CO_2}}{\dot{n}_C}\bar{h}_{CO_2}- \bar{h}_C-\frac{\dot{n}_{O_2}}{\dot{n}_C}\bar{h}_{O_2}$$
Knowing that the moles are $1$ to $1$ for all elements I get:
$$\frac{\dot{Q}}{\dot{n}_C}=\bar{h}_{CO_2}- \bar{h}_C-\bar{h}_{O_2}$$
$$\frac{\dot{Q}}{\dot{n}_C}=(\bar{h}_f^o)_{CO_2}+\Delta\bar{h}_{CO_2}- (\bar{h}_f^o)_{O_2}-\Delta\bar{h}_{O_2}-(\bar{h}_f^o)_{C}-\Delta\bar{h}_{C}$$
Now for my question, how do I find the values for the enthalpy of formation? I know that if the reactants were at $1$ atm I would just find the difference from $298K$ but because the reactants are not at STP for both T and P, I'm not sure if my tables, which are at $1$ atm, are applicable.

It can be limited to determine the difference in enthalpies of isothermal compression of O2 and expansion of CO2.

The enthalpy of formation is defined at a constant temperature of1 bar.

But if it was reformulated as a nonstandard reaction enthalpy at general pressure...

It is true that the standard enthalpy of reactions are tabulated for the temperature $T = \pu{298.15 K}$ and pressure $\pu{1 atm}$. As a consequence, it will be rare to find information at other pressures. However, we can use thermodynamics to calculate its value at another pressure by using the fact that $H$ is a state function. To illustrate this calculation, I consider that all amounts are stoichiometric.

The reaction is
$$ \ce{C(s) + O_2(g) -> CO2(g)} \tag{1} $$
Let $\xi$ denote the extent of the reaction, then the inlet of the reactor is
\begin{align}
  n_\ce{C}   &= n_\ce{C,0}  - \xi = n_\ce{C,0} - \xi \tag{2} \\
  n_\ce{O2}  &= n_\ce{O2,0} - \xi = n_\ce{C,0} - \xi \tag{3} \\
  n_\ce{CO2} &= \xi \tag{4} \\
\end{align}
Since the reactants are fed into the reactor stoichiometrically, then $n_\ce{CO,0} = n_\ce{C,0}$ by just reading Eq. (1). If the combustion is complete, then carbon is consumed completely and Eq. (2) states that $\xi = n_\ce{C,0}$. Thus, the outlet of the reactor is
\begin{align}
  n_\ce{C}   &= 0 \tag{5} \\
  n_\ce{O2}  &= 0 \tag{6} \\
  n_\ce{CO2} &= n_\ce{C,0} \tag{7}
\end{align}
Step 1. In this step we need to decrease the pressure of carbon and oxygen from $p_2$ to $p_1$. It is possible to prove that the change of enthalpy for a pure fluid at constant temperature is
\begin{equation}
  \mathrm{d}H =
  \left[V - T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_p\right]\mathrm{d}p \tag{8} 
\end{equation}
Applying Eq. (8) to carbon and oxygen gives the first enthalpy change
\begin{equation}
  \Delta H_1 = n_\ce{C,0} \int_{p_2}^{p_1} \left[V_\ce{C} -
  T\left(\frac{\partial V_\ce{C}}{\partial T}\right)_p\right] \mathrm{d}p +
  n_\ce{C,0} \int_{p_2}^{p_1} \left[V_\ce{O2} - 
  T\left(\frac{\partial V_\ce{O2}}{\partial T}\right)_p\right] \mathrm{d}p
  \tag{9}
\end{equation}
Step 2. In this step carbon and oxygen react to form carbon dioxide at $p_1$ and $T$. This second enthalpy change is the one tabulated
\begin{equation}
  \Delta H_2 = n_\ce{C,0}\Delta_\mathrm{r}H^\circ(p_1,T) \tag{10}
\end{equation}
Step 3. In this step we need to increase the pressure of carbon dioxide from $p_1$ to $p_2$ Applying Eq. (8) again gives
\begin{equation}
  \Delta H_3 = n_\ce{C,0} \int_{p_1}^{p_2} \left[V_\ce{CO2} - 
  T\left(\frac{\partial V_\ce{CO2}}{\partial T}\right)_p\right] \;\mathrm{d}p
  \tag{11}
\end{equation}
The final result is the sum of Eq. (9,10,11). Taking $n_\ce{C,0}$ as a common factor and by the properties of the integral, we answer
\begin{align}
  \Delta_\mathrm{r} H^\circ(p_2,T) =& n_\ce{C,0} \Delta_\mathrm{r}
  H^\circ(p_1,T) + n_\ce{C,0}
  \int_{p_1}^{p_2} \Bigg\{\left[V_\ce{CO2} - 
  T\left(\frac{\partial V_\ce{CO2}}{\partial T}\right)_p\right] - \\
  &\left[V_\ce{O2} - 
  T\left(\frac{\partial V_\ce{O2}}{\partial T}\right)_p\right] -
  \left[V_\ce{C} - 
  T\left(\frac{\partial V_\ce{C}}{\partial T}\right)_p\right]\Bigg\} \;\mathrm{d}p
  \tag{12}
\end{align}
Eq. (12) is exact. What is not exact is sometimes our knowledge of the molar volume of these substances as a function of pressure at constant temperature. In other words, an equation of state that is exact. If you have reliable data, use it and integrate Eq. (12). If not, the most sensible approach is:

We assume that gases behave ideally. Therefore, their enthalpies are independent of pressure and it is possible to prove that Eq. (8) yields zero (just plug $V = RT/p$).
We assume that solids are incompressible. Therefore, their molar volume is independent of the pressure at all temperatures.

The most simple expression for Eq. (12) then is
\begin{equation}
  \boxed{\Delta_\mathrm{r} H^\circ(p_2,T) = n_\ce{C,0} [\Delta_\mathrm{r}
   H^\circ(p_1,T) - V_\ce{C}(p_2 - p_1)]} \tag{13}
\end{equation}
where $V_\ce{C}$ is the molar volume of carbon. If you go to Wikipedia, you can read that the density of graphite is $\pu{2.266 g cm^-3}$. Therefore, the term in Eq. (13) is
\begin{equation}
  V_\ce{C}(p_2 - p_1) = \frac{M_\ce{C}}{\rho_\ce{C}}(p_2 - p_1) =
  \frac{\pu{12.012 g mol^{-1}}}{\pu{2266 \times 10^3 g m^{-3}}}
  (202650 - 101325)\pu{Pa} \approx \pu{0.537 J mol^{-1}}
\end{equation}
Given that enthalpy of reactions are in the order of $\pu{100 kJ mol^-1}$, this subtraction in Eq. (13) is negligible.
